# Preprocess views view to concat two dates and add variable

Tags: views, 8, hooks

I've been trying to get a custom format placed upon a date range with particular rules (Explained in code comments) within Drupal 8 views.

What I currently have worked with regard to me being able to get the original two dates and to customize them but what I can't seem to do is pass the result ($display_date_range) forward to the **fields view** TWIG file (views-view-field--group-travel.html.twig)

What I have so far

```
/*****************************************************************************
 * VIEWS VIEW PRE-PROCESS
 * @param $variables
 *****************************************************************************/
function cazloyd_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $id = $view->storage->id();

  // Handle the Group Travel Listing view
  if($id == 'group_travel_listing'){
    foreach ($view->result as $key => $result){
      // Get start date from view
      $date_start = $result->_entity->get('field_start_date')->getValue();

      // Get end date from view
      $date_end = $result->_entity->get('field_end_date')->getValue();

      $months_are_same = (date('n', strtotime($date_start[0]['value']))==date('n', strtotime($date_end[0]['value'])))?TRUE:FALSE;

      if($months_are_same){
        // Month of start and end date are same, show only the day part of the start date
        // e.g. 11 - 23 July 2017
        $formatted_date_start = date('j', strtotime($date_start[0]['value']));
      }else{
        // Event crosses over into new month, therefore show day and month part of start date
        // e.g. 11 July - 5 August 2017
        $formatted_date_start = date('j F', strtotime($date_start[0]['value']));
      }

      $formatted_date_end = date('j F Y', strtotime($date_end[0]['value']));

      // Build final date range
      $display_date_range = $formatted_date_start . ' - ' . $formatted_date_end;

      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($display_date_range);
      echo '</pre>';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hook_preprocess_views_view()` is used to alter the variables that are passed to a `views-view[...].html.twig` template file which is for the entire View, not just for the fields. It might make more sense for you to use `hook_preprocess_views_view_fields()` or `hook_preprocess_views_view_field()` since you are trying to alter the variables that are used in a `views-view-field[...].html.twig` template file (specific to the individual field, not the whole view).

See:

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_fields/7.x-3.x

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_field/7.x-3.x

Comment: Well, I'm not altering any existing fields, I am just reading two of them, but I do want to CREATE 1 new variable for each result and pass that through, but I get what you are saying about using the ...fields preprocessor instead

Comment: You could add a custom text field to the View and leave it empty, then alter that to include the balance value calculated from the other fields.